# How can I get the current date (w/o hour and minutes)?

Tags: flutter, dart

All I can see in the documentation is `DateTime.now()` but it returns the Timespan also, and I need just the date.

Answer (score 245):

Create a new date from `now` with only the parts you need:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
DateTime date = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

Hint: "new" is optional in Dart since quite a while

Comment: how to remove  00:00:00.000 ? should using replace ? ```date.toString().replaceAll("00:00:00.000", "")```

Comment: I'd use the intl package to format the date/time with custom date/time formats

Comment: if i know how do that , i would didnt comment :D

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/intl#date-formatting-and-parsing

Comment: Also, I can suggest this solution for getting "date" without creating a variable: `DateTime.now().copyWith(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0, microsecond: 0)`

Answer (score 77):

If you want only the date without the timestamp. You can take the help of intl package.

```
main() {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
    print(formattedDate); // 2016-01-25
}
```

This requires the intl package:

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

And finally import:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Answer (score 49):

You can get the current date using the DateTime class and format the Date using the DateFormat. The DateFormat class requires you to import the intl package so

add to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

and import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

and then format using

```
 final now = new DateTime.now();
 String formatter = DateFormat('yMd').format(now);// 28/03/2020
```

In case you are wondering How do you remember the date format(`DateFormat('yMd')`)? Then Flutter Docs is the answer

The [DateFormat class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) allows the user to choose from a set of standard date time formats as well as specify a customized pattern under certain locales.
The below formats are taken directly from the docs

```
/// Examples Using the US Locale:
///      Pattern                         Result
///      ----------------                -------
      new DateFormat.yMd()             -> 7/10/1996
      new DateFormat('yMd')            -> 7/10/1996
      new DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_US')   -> July 10, 1996
      new DateFormat.jm()              -> 5:08 PM
      new DateFormat.yMd().add_jm()    -> 7/10/1996 5:08 PM
      new DateFormat.Hm()              -> 17:08 // force 24 hour time

ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv
 HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz
 HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv
 HOUR_TZ                      jz
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

Hope this helps you to get Date in any format.

Comment: This example will work with intl package

Answer (score 15):

With dart extension

```
extension MyDateExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime getDateOnly(){
    return DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now(); // 30/09/2021 15:54:30
DateTime dateOnly = now.getDateOnly(); // 30/09/2021
```

Comment: Excellent, I was looking exactly for this. Personally, I would name this extension just "date". Also, it can be a property.

Answer (score 13):

this without using any package (it will convert to string)

```
  DateTime dateToday =new DateTime.now(); 
  String date = dateToday.toString().substring(0,10);
  print(date); // 2021-06-24
```

Answer (score 6):

## use this

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


getCurrentDate() {
       return DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(DateTime.now());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no class in the core libraries to model a date w/o time. You have to use `new DateTime.now()`.

Be aware that the date depends on the timezone: `2016-01-20 02:00:00` in Paris is the same instant as `2016-01-19 17:00:00` in Seattle but the *day* is not the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to print the year from a Timespan you can simply do:

```
DateTime nowDate = DateTime.now();
int currYear = nowDate.year; 

print(currYear.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you want device's current date just use this**

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.now();
 DateTime date = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

**Or if u want internet time, then use below plugin**

[ntp: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp/install)

```
 import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';

 final int offset = await NTP.getNtpOffset(
            localTime: DateTime.now(), lookUpAddress: "time.google.com");
        DateTime internetTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(milliseconds: offset));
DateTime internetTime = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

**Or if you need internet time but you don't want to use plugin then use api call**

```
"http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata"
{
  "abbreviation": "IST",
  "client_ip": "136.232.222.86",
  "datetime": "2022-09-30T17:13:10.299478+05:30",
  "day_of_week": 5,
  "day_of_year": 273,
  "dst": false,
  "dst_from": null,
  "dst_offset": 0,
  "dst_until": null,
  "raw_offset": 19800,
  "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "unixtime": 1664538190,
  "utc_datetime": "2022-09-30T11:43:10.299478+00:00",
  "utc_offset": "+05:30",
  "week_number": 39
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a more concise and single line format, based on Günter Zöchbauer's answer, you can also write:

```dart
DateTime dateToday = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day) ;
```

Though, it'll make 3 calls to DateTime.now(), the extra variable won't be required, especially if using with Dart ternary operator or inside Flutter UI code block.

Comment: I needed this to avoid using extra packages like `intl` thanks!

Comment: Calling it 3 times can lead to a weird bug if the user access the app at exactly midnight.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone need the simplest way to format date/time in flutter, no plugin needed:

```
var MONTHS = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

String formattedDateTime() {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    return now.day.toString()+" "+MONTHS[now.month-1]+" "+now.year.toString()+" "+now.hour.toString()+":"+now.minute.toString()+":"+now.second.toString();
}
```

example result: **1 Jan 2020 07:30:45**

Change:

- MONTHS array to show the month in any language
- the return string as needed: to show date only, time only, or date in
  different format (dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, etc.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
final now_date = DateFormat('d - M - yyyy ').format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: Quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

first go to pub.dev and get the intl package and add it to your project.

DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(the date you want to render . but must have the type DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

### Only one line with 'intl' package

```
String todayDate = DateFormat('yMd').format(DateTime.now());
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `day` in `DateTime.now()`