# How to create user history page similar to 'my activity' on google - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a history page in flutter. When I press 'a','b' or 'c' in my homepage, I want it to show what I pressed and the date I pressed the text on my history page similar to 'my activity' on google. This is what I came up with so far, and I don't even know if it is the best way to make it. It also has an error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Tile(text: Text("a")),
        Tile(text: Text("b")),
        Tile(text: Text("c")),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

int count = 0;

class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;
  Tile({this.text});

  @override
  TileState createState() => TileState();
}

class TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: widget.text,
      onTap: () {
        count++;
        print(count);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HistoryPage()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HistoryPageState createState() => HistoryPageState();
}

class HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(text),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How should I make my user history page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can put your click event in a `History List` and use `ListView` to show this `History List`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Tile(text: Text("a")),
        Tile(text: Text("b")),
        Tile(text: Text("c")),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

int count = 0;
List<History> historyList = [];

class History {
  String data;
  DateTime dateTime;

  History({this.data, this.dateTime});
}

class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;
  Tile({this.text});

  @override
  TileState createState() => TileState();
}

class TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: widget.text,
      onTap: () {
        count++;
        print(count);
        historyList
            .add(History(data: widget.text.data, dateTime: DateTime.now()));
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HistoryPage(),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HistoryPageState createState() => HistoryPageState();
}

class HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: historyList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
                ' ${historyList[index].data}   ${historyList[index].dateTime.toString()}'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only see the date, year, hour and minute?

Comment: you can use ${historyList[index].dateTime.year.toString()} ${historyList[index].dateTime.month.toString()} ${historyList[index].dateTime.day.toString()}

Comment: or use DateFormat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910686/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-w-o-hour-and-minutes-in-dart